# Remover brilho do olho na imagem

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, visão-computacional

Bom, eu estou tentando aplicar canny edge na imagem porem o brilho que está contido na pupila atrapalha o resultado obtido pois para ter uma borda com `cv2.Canny()` ou `feature.canny()` precisa que haja uma continuidade da mesma. Como tenho que aplicar filtro da media fica ainda pior por que essa região do brilho aumenta!

- Como fazer pra remover brilho da pupila?

Código para extrair borda:

```
from skimage import feature
from skimage.io import imread
import cv2
img = imread("../olho.jpg",as_gray=True)
img = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
borda = feature.canny(img)
```

Imagem original com ruido:

[image: IOG]

Imagem desejada(feito no paint!!):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bordas obtidas (com um buraco no local do brilho e as bordas do brilho):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Eu preciso dessas bordas certinha pois depois da extração vou aplicar transformada Hough para encontrar os circulos

Comment: Você possui a foto colorida? Ou somente escala de cinza?

Comment: Somente escala de cinza, tamanho 200x150

Answer (score 1):

#### Resultado

A imagem da esquerda é a original e a da direita a sem reflexo.

[image: Resultado]

#### Código

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request


resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvChy.jpg")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
copia = img.copy()

#Converte para Escala de Cinza
gray = cv2.cvtColor(copia,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Máscara para obter o que está no intervalo branco
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 215, 255)

#Lógica AND
mask_not = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
copia = cv2.bitwise_and(copia, copia, mask=mask_not )


#Interpolação da imagem para preencher os vazios
inpaint = cv2.inpaint(copia, mask, 3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

#Mostra a nova imagem e a original
cv2.imshow("Original / Inpaint", np.hstack([img, inpaint]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### Explicação

- Carrega a imagem e converte para escala de cinza (`gray`)
- Cria uma máscara da imagem, com os valores entre o intervalo 215 e 255 (próximo ao branco)
- Utiliza a lógica AND para retirar da imagem os pixels entre o intervalo definido na máscara `mask`
- Preenche os espaços vazios com a interpolação *Inpaint* de Alexandru Telea, prevendo o que deveria estar naquele local vazio

> Um ajuste fino provavelmente pode ser feito nos parâmetros de *InRange*: `mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 215, 255)`